# mongodb js getUsers method does not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Very simple question.
The database (nodejs, mongodb) is open, I can query other stuff.
According to the documentation I should be able to do this:

```
mydb.getUsers();
```

However I get a message telling me that the method doesn't exist. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Mongo directly within a Node.js application or from the terminal? if you're doing so from a Node.js application then what mongodb module are you using?

Comment: It is an express application. The module is mongodb@1.4.19

Comment: It doesn't look like that function exists according to the Mongo Node.js Driver docs: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/db.html